# Ajax autocomplete doesn't return correct value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I have an ajax autocomplete where it returns the full name of the user. However, when there are instances where some names or values are the same, it doesn't return the correct value. Rather, it returns the first value in the dropdown. Even if it has 4 same occurences, it still returns the first value.

[image]

When I click Stannis Arryn Baratheon, it returns Stannis Targaryen Baratheon.

Here is my php code (sql/php code; ad.php):

```
<?php
include('config.php');
if($_POST)
{
    if($_POST['search_keyword'])
    {
        $similar = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_keyword']);

        $result=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM person WHERE (firstName like '" . $_POST["search_keyword"] . "%' OR lastName like '" . $_POST["search_keyword"] . "%') AND residentOrNot = 'Yes' ");

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                //$name = $row['fullname'];
                //$copiedname = $row['fullname'];
                //$b_name= '<strong>'.$similar.'</strong>';
                //$final_name = str_ireplace($similar, $b_name, $name);
                ?>          
                <div class="show" align="left">
                    <span class="returnName"><?php echo $row["firstName"].' '.$row["middleName"].' '.$row["lastName"]; ?></span>
                    <span class="returnID" style="display:none"><?php echo $row['idPerson'];?></span> 
                </div>


            <?php
            }
        }

        else {
            ?>
                <div class="show" align="left">
                    <span class="returnMessage">No matching records found.</span>
                </div>
            <?php
        }

    }



    mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

HTML input form:

```
<form method="post" action="try.php" name="try">
<div class='web'>
    <input type="text" class="search_keyword" id="search_keyword_id" placeholder="Search" />
    <input type="hidden" name="resID" id="resID"/>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <input type="submit" name="try" value="Submit">
</div>
```

AJAX/JS/JQUERY CODE (i think this is where the problem occurs):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$(".search_keyword").keyup(function() 
{ 
    var search_keyword_value = $(this).val();
    var dataString = 'search_keyword='+ search_keyword_value;
    if(search_keyword_value!='')
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ad.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html)
                {
                    $("#result").html(html).show();
                }
        });
    }
    return false;    
});

jQuery("#result").on("click", function(e)
    {
    /*var $clicked = $(e.target);
    var $name = $clicked.find('.returnName').html();    
    var decoded = $("<div/>").html($name).text();
    $('#search_keyword_id').val(decoded);

    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    var $id = $clicked.find('.returnID').html();    
    var id = $("<div/>").html($id).text();
    $('#resID').val(id);
     */
    $name = $('span.returnName',this).html(); 
    $name = $("<div/>").html($name).text().toString();
    $('#search_keyword_id').val($name);
    $id = $('span.returnID',this).html(); 
    $id = $("<div/>").html($id).text().toString();
    $('#resID').val($id);



});

jQuery(document).on("click", function(e) { 
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    if (! $clicked.hasClass("search_keyword")){
    jQuery("#result").hide(); 
    }
});
});
</script>
```

It really returns the first value even if I click the second or third or fourth value. Where did I go wrong in my code? Please help me. Thank you so much!

Comment: You are trying to reinvent the wheel...its seems that the issue is on `("#result").on("click"` method...check that :)

Comment: I've looked into it. But I can't really seem to fix it...

Comment: Just for testing; can you place replace your method with this code instead: `jQuery("#result").on("click",".returnName" function(e)
    {
    $name = $(this).html();    
    $('#resID').val($name);
});`

Comment: Tried your code and it returns the actual div code... :(

Comment: So it is returning the html of the click span, right?..remember that is for testing if return the html of the clicked span...

Comment: Yes, it does.. i'm trying to use e.target, e.relatedTarget... it still doesn't work...

Comment: I'm gonna post a full answer...just wait....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is currently collecting all elements with class `returnName` in `#result`, and by calling `.html()` on that collection jQuery will only return the html of the first element found. The same goes for the your `returnID` search. This is why you are only getting the first returned entry.

Modify your #result click handler to only trigger for elements with class `show`, since that is the element that will contain your data.

```
jQuery("#result").on("click", ".show", function(e){
```

Then all you have to do is search for the elements with class `returnName` and `returnID` and call `.text()`.

```
var showName = $('.returnName',this).text();
var showId = $('.returnID',this).text();
$('#search_keyword_id').val(showName);
$('#resID').val(showId);
```

So all together

```
jQuery("#result").on("click", ".show", function(e){
    var showName = $('.returnName',this).text();
    var showId = $('.returnID',this).text();
    $('#search_keyword_id').val(showName);
    $('#resID').val(showId);
});
```

Though note there are probably better ways of returning your data, and utilizing it rather than transporting it in html elements. For example use [data-* attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) instead of using a separate `span` element to contain your id.

Another option is to use [jQuery-UI's autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) that does most of the client side work for you and just return the raw data in JSON format from your php script.

Comment: WOW!!!! YES, THE .SHOW CONTAINS THE DATA. I DIDN'T THINK IT WAS POSSIBLE TO INCLUDE ".SHOW" IN... jQuery("#result").on("click", ".show", function(e). THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR THIS. IT SOLVED MY PROBLEM. THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 1):

In your php code, change this:

```
<div class="show" align="left">
      <span class="returnName"><?php echo $row["firstName"].' '.$row["middleName"].' '.$row["lastName"]; ?></span>
      <span class="returnID" style="display:none"><?php echo $row['idPerson'];?></span> 
</div>
```

With this:

```
<div class="show" align="left">
    <span class="returnName" data-id="<?php echo $row['idPerson'];?>"><?php echo $row["firstName"].' '.$row["middleName"].' '.$row["lastName"]; ?></span>
</div>
```

And your new jquery function:

```
jQuery("#result").on("click","'.returnName" function(e)
{
     var choosenName = $(this).html();    
     var choosenId = $(this).data('id');
     $('#search_keyword_id').val(choosenName );
     $('#resID').val(choosenId );
});
```

Comment: IT WORKED!!!!! IT'S A DIFFERENT APPROACH FROM THE OTHER ANSWER (WHICH ALSO WORKED) BUT IT WORKED. WOW!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! THANK YOUUUUU HACKERMAN!!!!